# Suggested way to maintain view text description

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I am working on an app which requires a description to be shown for each record in the database based on the type.

For Eg.

If a customer is editing product1 of type A, the description corresponding to type A should be shown on the edit page of product1.

I can store the description in the types table. But i am looking for other options.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead with adding the description in the database for each type. It works pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a single table inheritance solution

http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance

Don't overuse STI though.

Comment: Could you please explain how STI can help? I am looking for alternatives to storing the description in the database